# How to process a large ActiveRecord result set in groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

I'm wondering if there is a way to take an array of ActiveRecord results (or any array, for that matter) and process it in groups of 25 or so. Something like this:

```
User.all.each(25) do |group|
    # Some code that works with this group of 25
end
```

I'm just looking to avoid doing multiple successive database queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rails 2.3 have this feature. You can specify `batch_size` parameter.

```
User.find_in_batches(:batch_size =>25) do |group|
    # Some code that works with this group of 25
end
```

You can find a good tutorial [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/152-rails-2-3-extras). Note that Rails will issue query for every 25 records. This is helpful to keep memory low if you are processing large number of records. If you want to split the results in multiple arrays, then you can use `in_groups_of` as suggested by Matt.

Comment: I had initially picked you answer but wound up going with Matt Rogish's because it avoids doing multiple queries.

Comment: I urge you to reconsider Bloudermilk. If you have a lot of records it's not only going to take a *lot* of time to fetch them, but also use up a lot of memory which could potentially make your server unresponsive. Processing them in small batches is much, much, MUCH better than fetching them all at once.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably looking for

```
Array#in_groups_of
```

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/3/1/new-in-rails-enumerable-group_by-and-array-in_groups_of

Comment: This will fetch the entire collection and store it all in memory. Bad idea.

Comment: Depends on how many rows and how big. There is a trade-off between query/network efficiency and memory use of the ruby process. Only the original question asker has the knowledge to say which applies to their problem

Comment: Ryan is right. `AR::Base#find_each` or `AR::Base#find_in_batches` is the solution.

Comment: If you're `find(:all)`ing a 10mil row table it's going to store it all in memory. Using in_groups_of will only accentuate that problem.